# Limit an EditText to 2 characters

Tags: android, view, android-edittext

I am developping an application for Android and I would like to limit an EditText to only 2 characters. Do you have an idea about this ?

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:maxLength="2"` to xml.

Answer (score 1):

In your EditText XML add this

```
android:maxLength="2"
```